# Como exibir formulário de um BD Access diretamente em um site?

Tags: microsoft-access, asp

Quero colocar as informações de um `.mdb` em um site, para disponibilizá-lo ao público.

Quando aberto no Access, possui formulários para realizar consultas.

Eu posso ter um site que exibe diretamente esses formulários na tela?

Ou eu teria que criar novos formulários e puxar as informações diretamente das consultas?

Comment: É possível se você usar Sharepoint.

Comment: Mas no SharePoint é necessário ser um usuário, não? Parece que não é possível ter acesso anônimo, e eu precisaria disso para abrir para o público em geral.

Comment: Você pode disponibilizar para acesso anônimo. Porém o Sharepoint não é tão "acessível" pois você precisa investir no seu ambiente ou usar o Sharepoint online (que não é algo muito barato)

Comment: Estou vendo aqui que o SharePoint online cobra por usuário. Quer dizer que eu vou ter que pagar por cada usuário que fizer acesso anonimamente?

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço muito o Sharepoint online, não sei te responder.

Comment: Se a estrutura não é grande e sua demanda de acesso for baixa converta sua base para o sql express ou my-sql, o access não foi feito para acesso via web.

Comment: Pretende abrir um formulário de consulta ou para preencher com dados na base de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você gostaria de exibir o formulário access diretamente em uma página web em ASP correto?

Se for isso digo que não é possível, o que você pode fazer é converter os dados seja de uma tabela ou consulta do access para o formato HTML estático podendo escolher um modelo de documento HTML ou usar o layout próprio do access, para isso bastando apenas clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima da tabela/consulta e selecionar exportar dados para o formato HTML.

Agora se você quiser algo dinâmico, você pode criar um servidor vinculado no SQL SERVER com seu MDB e a partir dai criar relatórios com o REPORTING SERVICES e disponibilizá-los no seu site.